# Is the following notation common in calculus books? $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (1-\sin^2\theta)\,d(\sin\theta)$

Tags: calculus, notation, change-of-variable

I am reading a calculus book.

> $$
> \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^3\theta \,d\theta
>  = \int_0^{\pi/2} (1-\sin^2\theta)\,d(\sin\theta)
>  = \left[\sin\theta-\frac{1}{3}\sin^3\theta\right]_0^{\pi/2}
>  = \frac{2}{3}.
> $$

Is the following notation common in calculus books?

> $$\int_0^{\pi/2} (1-\sin^2\theta)\,d(\sin\theta)$$

---

I think the author considers $\sin\theta$ as a variable.

So, I think the following notation is better:

> $$\int_0^1 (1-\sin^2\theta)\,d(\sin\theta)$$

Is the above notation uncommon in calculus books?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

American Calculus books usually use such notation in the context of Riemann-Stieltjes integration, but not for regular Riemann one.

I know the Russian analysis books use this notation very frequently. It's a nice shorthand for substitution.

Comment: gt6989b, Thank you very much for your answer and edit.

Comment: So @gt6989b in $ \int_0^{\pi/2} (1-\sin^2\theta)d(\sin\theta)$ is $\theta$ from 0 to pi/2 or is $\sin\theta$ suppose to be from 0 to pi/2 (not possible I know, but just clarifying; if it was d($\theta^2$), then would $\theta^2$ go from 0 to pi/2)?

Comment: @insipidintegrator Limits are in $\theta$ here but ideally should be changed to whatever is under the $d$. This works exactly like a change of variable (substitution)

Comment: Ok thanks @gt6989b